# How is a Unitary matrix a permutation?- Quantum pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, permutation, quantum-computing, basis

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508237) on quantum pattern matching and here it talks about a unitary matrix U which represents the oracle that flips a state's amplitude as a permutation over the computational basis. See page 3 right side fourth paragraph under equation (7).

Can someone explain to me what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unitary defined by equation (7) is a permutation because it sends every computational basis state to another computational basis state (as opposed to some superposition of computational basis states). In the matrix form, every column of U is filled with zeros except for one entry equal to one (and similarly for rows by invertibility). In other words, it is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Specifically, U sends the computational basis state |x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩ to the computational basis state |y, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩ where y = f(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) if x<sub>0</sub> = 0 and y = 1-f(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) if x<sub>0</sub> = 1. See equation (6).

---

Note that U does not flip the phase of any state. However, if we act with U on the state

|0, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩ - |1, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩

(where we neglect normalization) then the result is

(-1)^f(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) (|0, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩ - |1, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>⟩)

where the phase is flipped if and only if f(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) = 1. This is an example of [phase kickback](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/phase-kickback.html).